# Народна лемківська пісня "Под облачком". Яке значення діалектизму?

Tags: діалектизми, лемківський-діалект

Багато людей чули народну лемківську пісню ["Под облачком"](https://nashe.com.ua/song/5574) у виконанні сучасних виконавців. Тут є багато діалектизмів і більшість із них зрозумілі. За винятком одного — ***"окусо"***. Не можу знайти значення цього слова. Ось фрагмент тексу:

Моя мила, ти *окусо* єдна,
Любив я тя не рік та не два.
Далас ти мі зілля ся напити,
Не можливо мені без тя жити.

Яке ж його значення?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Отут](//youtu.be/hq3qTlmGCLM?t=1m47s), незважаючи на написаний долі текст («моя мила, ти окусо єдна»), доволі чітко співають: «ти **п**оку́со єдна». [Тут](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjnWmFHtGzI) і [тут](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfReLU3-mHo) навіть написано через «п-».

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 7, 1976. — Стор. 56.](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokusa):

> **ПОКУ́СА**, и, *жін[очий рід]*, *діал[ектне]*. Спокуса.

Найімовірніше, «окуса» — це текст з одруком, що розтиражували інтернетом.